# Change Input Text Value- Angular2

Tags: html, angular2-forms

I am working on angular 2 now... and I donno how to do this. In text box I need to type input value as 999-999-9999 format, While typing it should convert into xxx-xxx-9999. Again clicking on text box it should display it actual value.

If some one know how to do please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to create [custom pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) for that.

Comment: refer this https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2#readme

Comment: demo https://text-mask.github.io/text-mask/

Answer (score 0):

Use this :- [Angular2-text-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-text-mask)